# Let A, B two languages such that A=B does that implies that coA=coB

Tags: computability, complexity-classes

I'm getting to a problem while studying my computability and complexity exam.
If two languages A and B, such that A=B does that implies that coA=coB?

And in general if two language are describe by different TM such that they accept a certain input. One reject everything else, while the other doesn't define anything (loop)

For example: let A= {<>M| M accept every even number and reject on everything else}

B= {<>M| M accepts every even number and loop on everything else}

Are those two languages equals even if their complements are not?

Answer (score 1):

This question is not answerable, as you have not defined the notation coA.  Normally, we use the "co-" prefix with complexity classes (sets of languages) rather than languages (sets of strings).  See the definition of the [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) of a set.

Regarding the rest of your question, you have a confusion.  A language is a set of strings.  The language accepted by a Turing machine is the set of strings that cause the Turing machine to halt and accept.  So with your definitions of $A,B$, we have $A=B$: they are exactly the same language, and the complement of $A$ is equal to the complement of $B$.